# "Proper" Fact Table Design for Computing Irregular Snapshot Deltas

Tags: sql, database, data-warehouse, dimensional-modeling

I am designing my first Kimball-style dimensional database schema.

Most of the fact tables are periodic snapshots, and many reports are about comparing/delta-ing the snapshots.

However, in many cases, rows in one snapshot have no match in another snapshot, the kind of thing that is often handled with a FULL OUTER JOIN.

But I don't want the user queries to be super-complicated, so I want to generate "zero rows" so that there's always a match for any row between any two snapshots.

What is the "proper" way of doing this?

- Add the zero rows to the underlying table.
- Build a (materialized) view that dynamically adds the zero rows.
- Force the top-level queries to handle this situation with outer joins.

Thanks!

Comment: How are these snaphots uniquely identified?

Comment: Each snapshot is labeled by the type of estimate it is as well as the budget year for which it was submitted.

But, for instance, money might be allocated to a fiscal year in one snapshot but not another, or money might be allocated to a specific account in one snapshot, but that account doesn't exist in the other snapshot.